# Deploy Office Add-In through O365 Admin Center

Tags: office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

I have deployed an Office Add-in and uploaded through the O365 Admin Center
The Add-In appears in the Excel Ribbon but can use it as a message appears “We could not open the Add-In from LocalHost.
Should I modify anything in the Manifest File?
The Add-In was created with Yeoman and it´s addressed to “LocalHost:3000”. It´s just a template (taskpane example)
Many thanks in advance!!!
Regards, José.

Answer (score 1):

You have to host the add-in somewhere before you can deploy it to Office 365. Here is some Microsoft documentation of how to deploy the add-in to Azure https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website. The cost of this is low since it is just blob storage. Once it is deployed replace the URL in the manifest with the URL you get after deploying. Hope this helps!